# Using WindowBuilder + Scala, any good ideas?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, user-interface

I have here a small Scala console application and its working fine. I have now just one trouble: this application should be extended. One of the requests are, that there should be a GUI (AWT,SWT, Swig - doesnt matter, it just have to run on windows).

Well I really dont want to write my own GUI. I like tools like the WindowBuilder. Can I combine this effective? If I would create the GUI with the editor, I'll get generated Java code right? Could this be a problem? I just have to create a Mixin-Project, build the GUI and for each GUI element (Button or whatever with a listener) allocate a scala function. So I dont have to rewrite any of the scala stuff, just point to the function. Is this how it could work? Any suggestions? Thank you

Edit: For me it looks dirty to generate java code in a scala application, but well as I see there is no other solution.

Comment: I am not a Scala expert, but, as far as I know you can call Java code from Scala without any problems. So you can call your Java GUI from the main Scala application. The only slightly trickier part could be receiving events from the GUI (Java code calls Scala code). I would imagine that you define a callback as a Java interface that you can implement in Scala and call from Java (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349241/can-i-use-a-scala-class-which-implements-a-java-interface-from-java).

Comment: I do not think it is a dirty solution: AFAIK Scala has been developed on purpose to be compatible with Java. I would avoid mixing Java and Scala code in the same package though: I would clearly separate the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this several times and see no problem with mixing Java and Scala code in one project.

To make things easier for Scala compiler don't put Java and Scala classes into the same package.